# How to remove/delete laravel framework and vendor from my project?

Tags: php, laravel, vendor

I have an web app script. This script made by using `laravel` and `vendor`.
And I am still learning about these frameworks. Please tell me, how to delete this type framework without getting error script.

Comment: You need to provide what you ahve done with your webapp script.

Comment: i made this for getting google play store apps,games

Comment: the requirement is not entirely clear and there's no code to help explain. How can anyone realistically answer you?